# The scroll bar disappears - CSS

Tags: css, html

My problem is that when I re-size the browser window, instead of allowing the user to scroll in the horizontal direction, they simply disappear. As you can see, I have a `div` called product list, and my aim is to add a scroll bar when they do not fit on the screen. However, I still want avoid using the scroll bar for the entire page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title></title>
            <style type="text/css">
                * {
                    margin: 0px;
                    padding: 0px;
                    border: 0px;
                    overflow-y:hidden;

                }
                .productList {

                    overflow-x: scroll;
                    overflow-y:scroll;
                    position:fixed;
                    height:75%;
                    min-width:3000px;
                    max-width:5000px;

                }
                .header
                {
                    height:10%;
                    border-bottom: 1px groove black;
                    font-size:100px;
                    font-family:Verdana;
                }
                .menu {
                    width: 800px;
                    /* border-top-style: groove;*/
                    /*border-bottom-style: groove;*/
                    /*border-bottom-color: Black;*/
                    font-family: Georgia;
                    border:2px groove black;
                    border-left:0px;
                    height:4%;
                }
                .menuitem {
                    /*/border-top: 1px groove black;*/
                    border-bottom: 1px groove black;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    display: inline-block;
                    text-align: center;
                    padding: 4px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    background-color: White;
                    color: Black;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
                .menuitem:hover {
                    /*/border-top: 1px groove black;*/
                    border-bottom: 1px groove black;

                    text-decoration: none;
                    display: inline-block;
                    text-align: center;
                    padding: 4px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    background-color: #505050;
                    color: White;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
                .product
                {
                    display:block;
                    width:200px;
                    float:left;

                }

                .logo {
                    width: 200px; /*should be the same as product width*/
                    height: 100px; /*was 100px*/
                    position: fixed;
                    background-color: white;
                    display: block;
                    /*margin-bottom:100px;*/
                }
                .logos
                {
                    width:1400px;
                }
                .search
                {
                    height:11%;
                    border:1px groove gray;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body style="">
            <div>
                <div class="header">
                    Header
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="menuitem">Home</div>
                    <div class="menuitem">Home</div>
                    <div class="menuitem">Home</div>
                    <div class="menuitem">Home</div>
                </div>

                <!--should insert the serach bar here -->

                <div class="search">Sökfunktioners utrymme. TODO: show/hide funktion
                <br />
                Sökfält1, etc
                </div>
                <!--<div class="logos">
                    <img src="images/hm-logo.png" class="logo"/>
                    <img src="images/mq-logo.jpg" class="logo" />
                    <img src="images/kapp-ahl-logo.svg" class="logo" />
                    <img src="images/dressmann-logo.png" class="logo" />
                    <img src="images/jack-jones-logo.jpg" class="logo" />
                    <img src="images/lindex-logo.svg" class="logo" />
                    <img src="images/brothers-logo.png" class="logo" />
                </div>-->
                <div class="productList">

                  <div class="product">
                      <img src="images/hm-logo.png" class="logo" />
                      <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></div>
                      <img src="ex/hmprod.jpg" width="200" />
                      <img src="ex/hmprod.jpg" width="200" />
                      <img src="ex/hmprod.jpg" width="200" />


                </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <img src="images/mq-logo.jpg" class="logo" />
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></div>
                        <img src="ex/fossil-planbok.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <img src="images/jack-jones-logo.jpg" class="logo" />
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></div>
                        <img src="ex/fossil-planbok.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <img src="images/kapp-ahl-logo.svg" class="logo" />
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></div>
                        <img src="ex/fossil-planbok.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <img src="images/dressmann-logo.png" class="logo" />
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></div>
                        <img src="ex/fossil-planbok.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <img src="images/jack-jones-logo.jpg" class="logo" />
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></div>
                        <img src="ex/fossil-planbok.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="product">
                        <img src="images/lindex-logo.svg" class="logo" />
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></div>
                        <img src="ex/fossil-planbok.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <img src="images/brothers-logo.png" class="logo" />
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></div>
                        <img src="ex/fossil-planbok.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <img src="images/brothers-logo.png" class="logo" />
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></div>
                        <img src="ex/fossil-planbok.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <img src="images/brothers-logo.png" class="logo" />
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></div>
                        <img src="ex/fossil-planbok.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                        <img src="ex/clock.jpg" width="200" />
                    </div>
                  <!--  <div style="clear:both;"></div>-->
            </div><div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a position set to fixed.  You can try changing it to absolute.

Comment: look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JE26/)